# Getting id after inserting

Tags: c#, azure, windows-phone

I'm working with windows phone apps using windows azure as database and is there any windows azure script to return back to my windows phone apps an id that created automatically by windows azure? so i can catch the id value and use it in my windows phone? instead of calling these method that I think maybe slow

```
addressItem = await addressTable
                    .Where(table => table.placeId == hereRestDetail.placeId)
                    .ToCollectionAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

When inserting data to a Table with autogenerated Id in Azure, once insertion finished the Id is sent back to client application. So you can simply get the Id from the same object model used for insert operation :

```
.....
await addressTable.InsertAsync(addressModel);
var generatedId = addressModel.Id;
.....
```

[[Reference](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/347893e5-b92e-4d96-9b81-93e93ad95b80/windows-mobile-services-insertasync-return-identity)]